# After Installing Ubuntu College LAN not working?

Tags: authentication, lan

After installing Ubuntu college LAN is not working in Ubuntu but still working with windows 10. College LAN uses IEEE 802.1x authentication by username and password but not working on Ubuntu?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Network802.1xAuthentication

Answer (score 1):

Open your Network Manager and open the settings for your LAN. You should see something like this

[image]

Activate the 802.1x Security and select the right authentication method, username, password and you are ready.